# Cell content constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to redo my project programmatically with no storyboard. I have a tableView with a prototype cell.

The cell contains an imageView (briefcase), firstLabel (at the top) and secondLabel (right under the firstLabel). I tried to set up constraints, but for some reason secondLabel doesn't show at all, and the cell height doesn't adjust to the content height automatically.

Here's the code for the cell:

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    let briefcaseImage: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "briefcase"))
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.68, blue: 0.90, alpha: 1.00)
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        return img }()

    let firstLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label }()

    let secondLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.textAlignment = .right
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(briefcaseImage)
        self.contentView.addSubview(firstLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(secondLabel)
    
        //MARK: Constraints for the briefcaseImage
        briefcaseImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
        briefcaseImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        briefcaseImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.5).isActive = true
        briefcaseImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    
        //MARK: Constraints for the firstLabel
        firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
        firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: briefcaseImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        firstLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    
        //MARK: Constraints for the secondLabel
        secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.5).isActive = true
        secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: briefcaseImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        secondLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -11).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Also, when I run the app, I get this error in the debugger section:

```
Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

This is how the cell looks like (not what I want):

[image]

How do I fix my constraints properly so that the secondLabel shows and the cell height autoadjusts to the content height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it you must use stackView in your Cell, firstable return your heightForRowAt to UITableView.automaticDimension (you also remove heightForRowAt in this case because it is the default setting):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

After that in your Cell set the stackView and constraints to contentView not directly to cell like that:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

let briefcaseImage: UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "briefcase"))
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    img.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.68, blue: 0.90, alpha: 1.00)
    img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    img.clipsToBounds = true
    return img }()

let firstLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label }()

let secondLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label }()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.addSubview(briefcaseImage)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white

    //MARK: Constraints for the briefcaseImage
    briefcaseImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
    briefcaseImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    briefcaseImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.5).isActive = true
    briefcaseImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [firstLabel, secondLabel])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 2
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: briefcaseImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: briefcaseImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -11).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, good old Fabio, always with useful answers! Thanks a lot, will check it out when I get to my machine. Btw, how did you make your navigation items white? I couldn’t do it no matter what